# PK on temp table failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a trigger which declares a table variable.

```
DECLARE @TREarn_aaa table
  (
    aaaID bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Bbb decimal (18, 8) NULL,
    Ccc decimal (18, 8) NULL,
    Ddd decimal (18, 8) NULL,
    Eee decimal (18, 8) NULL
  );
```

On a rare occurrence, My table variable creation failed with following error -

```
System.data.sqlclient.sqlexception (0x80131904): the CURRENT TRANSACTION cannot be committed
AND
cannot support operations that write TO the log FILE. roll back the TRANSACTION. the CURRENT TRANSACTION cannot be committed
AND
cannot support operations that write TO the log FILE. roll back the TRANSACTION. **there IS already an object named** 'PK__#TREarn___70C9A75541DA7FD5' IN the DATABASE. could NOT CREATE CONSTRAINT
```

It failed as this name was already in use. Considering this is a table variable without naming PK, it should not happen.

Is it something like a known issue or I am missing something?

**EDIT** -

After @larnu comment I found a temporary table hidden in flow

CREATE TABLE #TREarn_aaa(aaaID bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,...);

However, the question still remains the same in context of temp table. Why did I get duplicate name? Is it an accident and can it be written off?

Unfortunately, I can't get version info as this came on customer DB on which I do not have access.

Comment: can you show us the trigger ?

Comment: The name `'PK__#TREarn___70C9A75541DA7FD5'` suggests a temporary table, *not* a table variable. Table Variable PK's get have a  7 character hex value after `PK__#` in the constraint's name. Also, the name of the (temporary) table would start with `#TREarn` and your table *variable's* does not. We don't have the full picture here.

Comment: In truth, the only way i can see this happening is that you actually have created a table with the `PRIMARY KEY` name explicitly defined as the name `PK__#TREarn___70C9A75541DA7FD5`.

Comment: In fact, as I forgot, you *cannot* name a constraint on a table variable; it generates an error. This further cements that the table variable and the error are completely unrelated.

Comment: I think @Larnu is spot on, check your code base for a temp table named #TREarn.

Comment: Side note, as well, you seem to be confusing temporary tables and table variables; these are *not* the same. Your title says temporary table, but then everything on your question is about the table variable; though the error (as I mentioned) is clearly about a temporary table.

Comment: Also post the version and service pack level `select @@version`.  If this repro's it's probably a bug, and might already be fixed.

Comment: Triggers are a horrible beast to maintain, I always advocate not use of them, even for log reasons. Creating a table variable smells a lot here. If you must write down a business logic keep it in the business layer

Comment: I'm curious how often this trigger is firing. "Random" isn't always all that random and I could absolutely see SQL creating a new "random" id for the primary key that matches an existing one depending on how many are being created and how long they exist.

Comment: Your edit didn't address anything in the comments apart from your misunderstanding of the difference between table variables and temporary tables.... Please actually address the comments, don't ignore them.

Comment: I, on the other hand doubt it, @KennethFisher . A table variable's PK would have a value like `PK__#A2DC837__6894C54B1A689ECC`. That's a 7 digit hex value, followed by a 16 digit hex value. That means you have 16^7 * 16^16, or 16^23 different possible values; that's 4,951,760,157,141,521,099,596,496,896 different possible values.

Comment: You are right, I have a temp table hidden in flow 

CREATE TABLE #TREarn_aaa(aaaID bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,...);

However, question still remain same in conext of temp table. Why did i get duplicate name? Is it accident and can be written off?

Unfortunately I can't get version info as this cane on customer DB on which I do not have access.

Comment: @Larnu - the numbers needed to get a clash are nowhere near that high https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/236796/3690 - it is only in the tens of thousands of concurrent instances of `#TREarn_aaa` before it becomes more probable than not that there will be a collision

Comment: It is much higher than the number you state in that link though, @MartinSmith, that isn't for table variables.

Comment: @Larnu they aren't getting the issue due to a table variable as you yourself point out. The edit to the question shows the issue is with a temp table `CREATE TABLE #TREarn_aaa(aaaID bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,...);`

Comment: My comment above is about **table variables**, @MartinSmith . *"A **table variable's** PK would have a value like PK__#A2DC837__6894C54B1A689ECC. That's a 7 digit hex value, followed by a 16 digit hex value."*